# using value of a wrapper class in calculating a value

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I have controller code where I want to calculate a specific value. This code uses a calculated value from a wrapper class `RevMonths4` which has a variable `RevenueTotCY`. However, the procedure is not accepting this value from wrapper class saying **Variable does not exist: RevMonths4**:

```
public  Double Dist_CY {
        get {
        if (Dist_Tot != 0){
        return ((double.valueof(RevMonths4.get('RevenueTotCY')) / Dist_Tot) - 1);
        }
        else return 0;
  }
 set;
}
```

Snippet of Wrapper class which is working perfectly fine:

```
public class RevMonths4
{
public String Rep_Id { get; set; }
public Double RevenueCY { get; set; }
public Double GoalCY { get; set {GoalCY = Value; RevenueTotCY = GoalCY + RevenueCY;} }
public Double RevenueTotCY { get; set; }    
public Double RevenueLY { get; set {RevenueLY = Value; if(RevenueLY != 0) {RepGrowth = ( RevenueTotCY / RevenueLY) - 1;} else {RepGrowth = 0;}} }
public Double RepGrowth { get; set; }
public Double T12CY { get; set {T12CY = Value; if (T12CY != 0){TerritoryCY = RevenueTotCY / T12CY;} else {TerritoryCY = 0;}} }
public Double T12LY { get; set {T12LY = Value; if(T12LY != 0) {T12Growth = ( T12CY / T12LY) - 1; TerritoryLY = RevenueLY / T12LY;} else {T12Growth = 0; TerritoryLY = 0;}} }
public Double T12Growth { get; set; }
public Double TerritoryCY { get; set; }
public Double TerritoryLY { get; set; }
public Double MarketCY { get; set {MarketCY = Value; if (MarketCY != 0) {MktShrCY = T12CY / MarketCY;} else {MktShrCY = 0;}} }
public Double MarketLY { get; set {MarketLY = Value; if(MarketLY != 0) {MarketGrowth = ( MarketCY / MarketLY) - 1; MktShrLY = T12LY / MarketLY;} else {MarketGrowth = 0; MktShrLY = 0;}}  }
public Double MarketGrowth { get; set; }
public Double MktShrCY { get; set; }
public Double MktShrLY { get; set; }

public RevMonths4(String rep, Double revcy, Double golcy, Double revly, Double t12cy, Double t12ly, Double mktcy, Double mktly)
{
Rep_Id = rep;
RevenueCY = revcy;
GoalCY = golcy;
RevenueLY = revly;
T12CY = t12cy;
T12LY = t12ly;
MarketCY = mktcy;
MarketLY = mktly;
}
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You say your class is called RevMonth4, but in your code it says RevMonths4 (note the extra s). Is the variable RevenueToTCY static in your wrapper class? Can you show us your wrapper?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo while posting the question.. it is `RevMonths4`

Comment: Is there an instance of the `RevMonths4` class in a variable named `RevMonths4` in the class where the `Dist_CY` code is at? (It doesn't appear so)

Answer (score 3):

In the first block of code (Double Dist_CY), I don't see a declaration for RevMonths4.  That line would be something like:

RevMonths4 RV = new RevMonths(fill in appropriate constructor info);

If you want functions in the class you can call without creating an instance of the class, you need to declare those functions as static.  More info on static functions here:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_static.htm

Answer (score 0):

Silly thing but make sure your wrapper class is public and not private.
If that is already public, it would really help if you can post the entire code.

Comment: I have updated my question with code for wrapper class.. and as you can see its public and not private so that is not the probelm..